# How Can I eliminate this dot? I was testing Implicit Conversion

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have been trying to use the `Int` type like this: `10 twotimes`.

It is similar to Akka's duration package which allows to write for example `10 minutes` and `5 seconds`.

I did the following:

```
object ImplicitConversion2 {
  class Test(val a:Int) {
    def threetimes = a * 3
  }

  implicit def IntToTest(e:Int) = new Test(e)

  5.threetimes                 //> res0: Int = 15
  10.threetimes                //> res1: Int = 30
  11.threetimes                //> res2: Int = 33
}
```

In this case, I can use `threetimes` like `10.threetimes`, that is with a dot between `10` and `threetimes`. I want to eliminate the dot between the `Int` and `threetimes`.

But if I write `5 threetimes`, an error occurs.
How can I do that?

Comment: my english expression is extremely poor, so I wondered that, and now I don't have to  worry that Thanks! chris

Comment: No problem. Another thing, maybe in your first line you wanted to use `threetimes` instead of `twotimes`? It's not a big deal, just saying ;)

Comment: yes, I wanted to use threetimes method which allows to multiply someething 3 times, because I just want to test it

Comment: You'll still have problems with semicolon inference if trying to use several of these expressions on subsequent lines. That's why postfix ops aren't recommended. If you insist, you can either include a line of whitespace between them, use semicolons on each line, or put each expression in parens.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Scala are you referring to? With version 2.10.1 I get a *feature warning*, namely that I should add the following

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
```

to activate implicit conversions. After doing so, as you said, `10.threetimes` works fine, but for `10 threetimes` I get another *feature warning* which tells me to add:

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
```

to enable postfix operators. After doing so, everything works fine.

**EDIT:** Here is an excerpt from the original SIP (to be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nlkvpoIRkx7at1qJEZafJwthZ3GeIklTFhqmXMvTX9Q/edit)) which gives the reason why postfix operators are now discouraged by default (i.e., you will get a warning if you use them; in later versions this might turn into an error instead of a warning):

> **postfixOps.** Only where enabled, postfix operator notation  (expr op)  will be allowed. Why keep the feature? Several DSLs written in Scala need the notation. Why control it? Postfix operators interact poorly with semicolon inference. Most programmers avoid them for this reason.

Comment: I'm using scala 2.10.0 version, I'll install new version of it, and test it, Thanks chris!

Comment: Did you try, whether my above solution works for you (with your current version of Scala)? (I think it should.), i.e., just add the above mentioned `import`s to your file.

Answer (score 3):

As Luigi Plinge correctly states in his comment, the compiler tries to use the line after a call to a postfix operator as argument. If you look at the error message it becomes clear:

```
<console>:10: error: Int does not take parameters
          3 threetimes
```

This error means, that it tries to use something as an argument, where it doesn't belong. The fact, that using dot-notation fixes this error should make it obvious, what goes wrong. The only way to safely use postfix operators is to pass them as arguments, where either the `)` or the `,` terminates the expression.

```
def foo(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y

foo(4 threetimes, 8 threetimes)
```

Comment: I have met with the problem, Thanks for your suggestion!